# .htaccess RewriteRule to redirect all to root

Tags: url, htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect every request to root by using RewriteRules in my .htaccess file (later on I will copy them to a vhost file). I tried something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

This works, but obviously this generates an endless loop. I think I need a RewriteCond that excludes the root. So I tried something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

But sadly this does not seem to work. I have been searching around for some time know but I only come across RewriteRules that remove or add the slash with every url (which I don't want). Help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Apache2 + mod_rewrite on a linux machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably more a question for serverfault I guess.
The root is just a /.
So you have to tell it starts with /, `^/`, and also that it ends right after, so you have to add a $, leading to the following line.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
```

Comment: Doh, I see it now. Thanks it worked! And I thought I created it under StackOverflow, my apologies. Can a mod transfer this question?

Comment: You're welcome. Actually this is a duplicate of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437375/apache-mod-rewrite-for-everything-except-root

Comment: You are totally right, I did not found that question in my search for duplicates.

Comment: Actually I think the original post I pasted here has nothing to do on StackOverflow, all this should be on ServerFault as it's part of server administration.